# Dtreeviz NameError

Tags: python, graphviz, lightgbm, dtreeviz

I installed dtreebiz and wanted to make a three plot. I did exactly what example codes say as below, but keep getting "NameError: name 'dtreeviz' is not defined".

```
from dtreeviz.trees import *

viz = dtreeviz(lgbm,
               x_data = df_X_train,
               y_data = df_y_train,
               target_name = TARGET,
               feature_names = df_X_train.columns.tolist(),
               tree_index = 0)

viz
```

I checked the version using `pip show dtreeviz` and confirmed version 2.1.3 is installed. I am using Spyder mostly but I also tried the same thing with Jupyter Notebook and got the same error.

Comment: _I did exactly what example codes say as below_ Can you post links to these examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was some compatibility issues from version 1 to 2.
I would suggest to start using the new 2.0 API :)

For the old API, you could try:

```
from dtreeviz import *
viz = dtreeviz(lgbm,
               x_data = df_X_train,
               y_data = df_y_train,
               target_name = TARGET,
               feature_names = df_X_train.columns.tolist(),
               tree_index = 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```
import dtreeviz
```

to your code (see the Quick Start in dtreeviz [github](https://github.com/parrt/dtreeviz) page). Importing all the symbols from `dtreeviz.trees`, like you're doing with

```
from dtreeviz.trees import *
```

imports the symbols in the `trees` module only.

Comment: Thank you very much, but this time I got the error: 
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable.

I also tried "from dtreeviz.trees import dtreeviz" and this case got ImportError: cannot import name 'dtreeviz' from 'dtreeviz.trees' (c:\program files\python39\lib\site-packages\dtreeviz\trees.py)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add .model with dtreeviz like as follows:

```
dtreeviz import *
viz = dtreeviz.model(lgbm,
               x_train,
               y_train,
       target_name = ‘TARGET column name’,
       feature_names = x_train.columns
         )

viz.view()
```